# "The remote end hung up unexpectedly" when running git pull

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone a huge file from remote to local, but it shows the following errors when I run `git pull`

```
remote: Counting objects: 18127, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score -1):

In magento I had many files, so I solved it using the following commands:

```sh
git config --global http.postBuffer 1000M
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 500M
git config --global core.compression 0
```